# Optimising a large SP with lots of insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, insert

I have a stored procedure that does about 50 insert statements on a single table.  I'm having issues where this is creating a massive database and large log file.

I've seen references to splitting the script into batches to help, but I'm not entirely sure how best to do that.

Would it be to place GO commands after each insert, or BEGIN END statements?
Or is there another method I'm not aware of.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

SAMPLE:

`

```
-- E1.005
INSERT INTO [Results] ([Table], EstabID, ID, PersonID, EpiNo, ProdType,
    [ErrorLevel], [ErrorCode], [RowID], [QueryField], [ValCode], [ValRule],[ErrorMessage])
SELECT
    'A' AS [Table], 
    A.EstabID, 
    A.ID, 
    A.PersonID, 
    A.EpiNo, 
    A.ProdType,
    'Critical' AS [ErrorLevel], 
    'E1.005' AS [ErrorCode],
    A.RowID,
    'EstabID' AS [QueryField], 
    'If EstabID second position (starting from left) is not in (''1'',''2'',''4'',''5'') then return Error Code' AS [ValCode], 
    'Critical Error: If establishment sector not 1, 2, 4 or 5.' AS [ValRule], 
    'Critical Error: The Establishment ID character in the second position of this field (which indicates the associated establishment sector) needs to be either 1,2,4 or 5 for this to be a valid code' 
        AS [ErrorMessage]
FROM  tmp_A A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Results B ON A.RowID = B.RowID AND LEFT(B.ErrorCode,2) IN ('E1','W1')
WHERE ISNULL(A.ID,'') <> '' and SUBSTRING(A.ID,2,1) not in ('1','2','4','5') AND B.RowID IS NULL;

-- E1.006
INSERT INTO [Results] ([Table], EstabID, ID, PersonID, EpiNo, ProdType,
    [ErrorLevel], [ErrorCode], [RowID], [QueryField], [ValCode], [ValRule],[ErrorMessage])
SELECT
    'A' AS [Table], 
    A.EstabID, 
    A.ID, 
    A.PersonID, 
    A.EpiNo, 
    A.ProdType,
    'Critical' AS [ErrorLevel], 
    'E1.006' AS [ErrorCode],
    A.RowID,
    'EstabID' AS [QueryField], 
    'If EstabID third and fourth position (starting from left) is blank or not zero filled then return Error Code' AS [ValCode], 
    'Critical Error: If region is not zero filled.' AS [ValRule], 
    'Critical Error: The Establishment ID characters in the 3rd and 4th position of the string (which identify the region code - a two character string) zero filled where no specific region identifier forms part of the state establishment identifier.' 
        AS [ErrorMessage]
FROM  tmp_A A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Results B ON A.RowID = B.RowID AND LEFT(B.ErrorCode,2) IN ('E1','W1')
WHERE ISNULL(A.EstabID,'') <> '' and (SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,3,1) = ' ' OR SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,4,1) = ' ') AND B.RowID IS NULL;

-- E1.007
INSERT INTO [Results] ([Table], EstabID, ID, PersonID, EpiNo, ProdType,
    [ErrorLevel], [ErrorCode], [RowID], [QueryField], [ValCode], [ValRule],[ErrorMessage])
SELECT
    'A' AS [Table], 
    A.EstabID, 
    A.ID, 
    A.PersonID, 
    A.EpiNo, 
    A.ProdType,
    'Critical' AS [ErrorLevel], 
    'E1.007' AS [ErrorCode],
    A.RowID,
    'EstabID' AS [QueryField], 
    'If EstabID in positions 5 to 9 (starting from left) does not have a length of 5 then return an error.  If EstabID in positions 5 to 9 (starting from left) is blank or null then return error code' AS [ValCode], 
    'Critical Error: If organisation is not 5 characters long and/or zero filled.  This can be alphanumeric' AS [ValRule], 
    'Critical Error: The Establishment ID characters in positions 5 to 9 of the string (which identify the establishment - a five character alphanumeric string) need to be left justified and zero filled.  Where a fully numeric identifier is used in the jurisdiction this part of the string must be five characters in length.' 
        AS [ErrorMessage]
FROM  tmp_A A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Results B ON A.RowID = B.RowID AND LEFT(B.ErrorCode,2) IN ('E1','W1')
WHERE ISNULL(A.EstabID,'') <> '' AND (SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,5,1) = ' ' OR SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,6,1) = ' ' OR
    SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,7,1) = ' ' OR SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,8,1) = ' ' OR SUBSTRING(A.EstabID,9,1) = ' ') AND B.RowID IS NULL;`
```

Comment: are some of inserts with same value, or they are all different?

Comment: code added.  Some values are the same Farhang, as you can see

Comment: Those are some nasty (from an optimization perspective) `WHERE` clauses. You may want to look into making them [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). You could also combine the substring checks for blanks into extracting a single substring and testing it for a blank.

Comment: Why dont you directly insert in to results instead of those temp tables?